# Find matches in text using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an Elasticsearch index of words and word pairs, like:

```
python
ruby
ruby on rails
NLP
Javascript
Agoraphobia
...
```

And an input text, like:

```
Both Python and Ruby (or Ruby on Rails) could be used for NLP purposes.
```

What I need is to find direct matches of entries from the index in the text. So output should look like:

```
python
ruby
ruby on rails
```

What is the way to compare the whole index against the text using Elasticsearch?

Comment: I've answered this here: [Extract keywords (multi word) from text using elastic search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581029/extract-keywords-multi-word-from-text-using-elastic-search). It does seem to do exactly what you're looking for. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yup, `shingle` is a cool thing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a database or using elastic to store it through memory? If just using elasticsearch -curl -XGET 'http://localhost:_yourIP/folder/_search?q=word:_word'

Comment: The input text is just a String from the outside, the words/words pairs are in the ES index. What I really want is batch-processing of all entries in the index against the text provided

Comment: So in other words it's a kind of optimization of matching: I don't want to take entries from the index, one by one, compare it for presence in the text, but I want to feed the whole index, and have a list of matches (if any), as a list of ES entries (e.g. index id, other data around..)