# Extract keywords (multi word) from text using elastic search and return offset of the searched words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a lot of keywords that I want to extract from a query and tell the position(offset) of were the keywords are in that text
So this is my progress I created two custom analyzers keyword and shingles:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "my_analyzer_shingle": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "shingle"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer_keyword",
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer_shingle"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And here are the keywords that I say:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 2000,
    "hits": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "keyword": "python programming"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "keyword": "facebook"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "keyword": "Microsoft"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "keyword": "NLTK"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "keyword": "Natural language processing"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I make a query something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "keyword": "I post a lot of things on Facebook and quora"
    }
  }
}
```

So with the code above I get

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0.009332742,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "your_type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.009332742,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "keyword": "facebook"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "your_type",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.009207102,
        "_source": {
          "id": 4,
          "keyword": "quora"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I don't know were in the text are that words the offset of those words:
I want to know that quora start at index 40. But not to highlight them between tags or something like this.

I want to mention that my post is based on this post

> [Extract keywords (multi word) from text using elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581029/extract-keywords-multi-word-from-text-using-elastic-search/33582295?noredirect=1#comment115608644_33582295)