# Extract Keywords From Text Using Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of keywords. I want to query the keywords table given a string of text and return the keywords found. I was able to get this working in Elasticsearch using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581029/extract-keywords-multi-word-from-text-using-elastic-search). Is this something that is possible in Postgres using the available text search functions? How would the text search query look?

Example:

```
Keywords table:

id    keyword
--------------
1     thousand eyes
2     facebook
3     superdoc
4     quora
5     your story
6     Surgery
7     lending club
8     ad roll
9     the honest company
10    Draft kings


Given the following text: "I saw the news of lending club on facebook, your story and quora"

Output:

id    keyword
--------------
3     facebook
4     quora
5     your story
7     lending club
```

Comment: `select regexp_matches('1 2 3 4 5 666', '\m(1|3 4|6)\M', 'g');`

Comment: Could you explain how that does the keyword matching from the keyword column?

Comment: It was just an example. Instead of constant value `'\m(1|3 4|6)\M'` you should to build it dynamically using your `Keywords` table: `select '\m(' || string_agg(keyword, '|') || ')\M' from Keywords;` The complete query could be: `select regexp_matches('I saw the news of lending club on facebook, your story and quora', (select '\m(' || string_agg(keyword, '|') || ')\M' from Keywords));` Then join it with `Keywords` to get IDs.

Comment: Do you know if I can use the text search functions to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your desired answer is pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE 
    'I saw the news of lending club on facebook, your story and quora' LIKE 
        '%'||keyword||'%' ;
```

Now I don't know what you want to do with case, or word boundaries, or what you expect for performance.  But your example didn't address any of those.

Comment: This should work for now. In the future, what would be some performance enhacements to this query?

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization.  If you have performance issues in the future, ask another question then.